# Initializing unsigned int returned by sscanf

Tags: c, scanf

The variable (a, r, g, b) will contain an arbitrary value left from earlier computations.

```
unsigned int parse_colour( const char *str )
{
    unsigned int a, r, g, b;
    int ret;

    if( !str || !*str ) return 0;

    if( strlen( str ) == 1 ) return (unsigned int)atoi( str );

    if( str[0] == '0' && str[1] == 'x' ) {
            ret = sscanf( str, "0x%x", &a );
    } else {
            ret = sscanf( str, "%u %u %u %u", &a, &r, &g, &b );
    }

    if( ret == 1 ) {
            return a;
    } else if( ret == 2 ) {
            return 0xff000000 | ( (a & 0xff) << 8 ) | (r & 0xff);
    } else if( ret == 3 ) {
            return 0xff000000 | ( (a & 0xff) << 16 ) | ( (r & 0xff) << 8 ) | ( g & 0xff);
    } else if( ret == 4 ) {
            return ( (a & 0xff) << 24 ) | ( (r & 0xff) << 16 ) | ( ( g & 0xff) << 8 ) | (b & 0xff);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The code uses a variable that has not been initialized, leading to unpredictable or unintended results.

False positive?

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: a,r,g,b are set with the sscanf statements before they are used for anything

Comment: Just zero initialize and be safe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are receiving a warning, it could be that the compiler see 2 paths

```
ret = sscanf( str, "0x%x", &a );
ret = sscanf( str, "%u %u %u %u", &a, &r, &g, &b );
```

The first path does not initialize `r g b`.
Later, the code uses `r g b` and does not "know" how the `sscanf()`s and your `if()`s combine to prevent inadvertent usage of an uninitialized variable.

There is no performance downside to initializing `a,r,g,b` to 0 as suggested by @Juraj Blaho.  You are calling `sscanf()` and *that* chews up a lot of CPU.
It is a "false positive", but I'd recommend changing your code to prevent any warnings.

---

Minor ideas:

Porting issue issue: since a `unsigned int` is only certain to be at least 2 bytes, `(a & 0xff) << 24` should be `(a & 0xffUL) << 24`.  Likewise `(r & 0xffUL) << 16 )` and the return type `unsigned long parse_colour()`.
Alternatively there are the types `uint32`, etc.

Not sure of the need for `if( strlen( str ) == 1 ) return (unsigned int)atoi( str );`.  Can't see how that affects things.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are getting this warning is because `sscanf` can fail (at least the compiler thinks so) in which case `a` will remain uninitialised when you return a value based on it a few lines later.